# R: How to plot use function which find a root

Tags: r, plot

I construct a user-function:

```
find.c <- function(q) { f <- function(c) {
(log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 6) * q^6 * (1-q)^(6-6) * factorial(6) / factorial(6) / factorial(6-6)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 5) * q^5 * (1-q)^(6-5) * factorial(6) / factorial(5) / factorial(6-5)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 4) * q^4 * (1-q)^(6-4) * factorial(6) / factorial(4) / factorial(6-4)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 3) * q^3 * (1-q)^(6-3) * factorial(6) / factorial(3) / factorial(6-3)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 2) * q^2 * (1-q)^(6-2) * factorial(6) / factorial(2) / factorial(6-2)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 1) * q^1 * (1-q)^(6-1) * factorial(6) / factorial(1) / factorial(6-1)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 0) * q^0 * (1-q)^(6-0) * factorial(6) / factorial(0) / factorial(6-0)
 - log(7.2)
)}                                                                                          
 g <- uniroot(f, lower=0, upper=100, extendInt = "yes")[1]                                 
 g}
```

And I tried to plot:

```
plot(x = seq(0, 1 , 0.001), find.c(x))
```

then it gives me: "Error in uniroot(f, lower = 0, upper = 100, extendInt = "yes") :
f() values at end points not of opposite sign"

Also is ther any way I can use 'for' loop to simplify this function? I tried may way with for but function inside function makes very complicated.

Comment: Does your function cross 0 within the range 0 - to - 100? You can't find the zero point if there isn't one.

Comment: find.c(0.1), find.c(0.001) , etc gives me output, yes.

Comment: Does `plot(x, sapply(x, find.c))` show what you expect?

Comment: Also is there anyone can explain me why I should use sapply? For instance 'sin' does't need sapply, but this use function need it. Is that because my function cannot have vector or list input?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @r2evans suggestion, but I think you can restructure this to be simpler without the nested function.

First, define `f` with both `c=` and `q=` as arguments:

```
f <- function(c,q) {
(log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 6) * q^6 * (1-q)^(6-6) * factorial(6) / factorial(6) / factorial(6-6)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 5) * q^5 * (1-q)^(6-5) * factorial(6) / factorial(5) / factorial(6-5)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 4) * q^4 * (1-q)^(6-4) * factorial(6) / factorial(4) / factorial(6-4)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 3) * q^3 * (1-q)^(6-3) * factorial(6) / factorial(3) / factorial(6-3)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 2) * q^2 * (1-q)^(6-2) * factorial(6) / factorial(2) / factorial(6-2)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 1) * q^1 * (1-q)^(6-1) * factorial(6) / factorial(1) / factorial(6-1)
 + log(7.2 + 6 * c * q - 0) * q^0 * (1-q)^(6-0) * factorial(6) / factorial(0) / factorial(6-0)
 - log(7.2)
)}
```

Then loop over each of the `q=` values:

```
mapply(function(...) uniroot(...)[[1]], 
   list(f), q=seq(0,1,0.001), lower=0, upper=100, extendInt="yes")

#   [1] 0.000000 1.076564 1.076460 1.076375 1.076291 1.076206 1.076122
#   [8] 1.076037 1.075953 1.075868 1.075784 1.075699 1.075614 1.075530
#   etc
```